# how can i solve: like Operator doesn't work in data set c#

Tags: dataset

i have a dataset and i added a aquery in table adabter of dataset added this sql statement but like operator doesnt work properly i must write full name to give me results and doesnt give any result if i write part of name
SELECT
students.id as id, students.name as name,courseDetails.id as idCourse, courseDetails.courseNumber as courseNumber, courseMenus.courseName as courseName
FROM students INNER JOIN
courseDetails ON students.id = courseDetails.studentId INNER JOIN
courseMenus ON courseDetails.courseCode = courseMenus.code
where  courseDetails.fasl=1 and students.name like '%'+@name+'%'

[sql statement in dataset query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5syOR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

hullo i tried to write after where and worked well but i don't  understand
the reason, here the solution:

where courseDetails.fasl=1 and students.name+students.name like '%'+@name+'%'
thank you